# How to show just an elements in React Native's Flatlists

Tags: reactjs, native, selection, flatlist

Is there a way to show just an element in a flatlist?

```
    <FlatList
                style={styles.flatList}
                data={WorkoutList}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <View style={styles.card}>
                        <Text>item.name</Text>
                    </View>}
            />
```

This code will show all the names.
Can I show just the name in position "i", and with a button increase "i" to see the next one till the end?

So instead of:

```
Mark
Luke
Paul
```

I want something like:

```
Mark
NEXTBUTTON
```

And when I press next

```
Luke
NEXTBUTTON
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not showing the list why use `FlatList`.
You need a state to tract which index to show and show only the data of that index.

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const showNextIndex = () => {
  if(index < workoutList.length)
    useState(index + 1);
}
...
<Text>{workoutList[index].name}</Tex>
<Button onPress={showNextIndex}>Next</Button>
```

Comment: But this is not working in my case because WorkoutList is not an array and I get it from firebase like this       ....... .get()
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const workoutDoc = doc.data()
        workoutDoc.id = doc.id
        workoutList.push(workoutDoc)
    })
    WorkoutRetrived(workoutList)